# VK_api(wall.post)

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пытаясь написать бота, который бы постил текст в группе с открытой стенной, столкнулся с проблемой.

vk_api возвращает мне ошибку `214`:

> Публикация запрещена. Превышен лимит на число публикаций в сутки, либо
>   на указанное время уже запланирована другая запись, либо для текущего
>   пользователя недоступно размещение записи на этой стене

Вероятно я туплю, но не могу понять из-за чего он выдает эту ошибку, т.к постить пытаюсь в группе c открытой стеной.

```
import vk_api
from typing import Any
from vk_api import VkUpload
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from requests import get as request
import random
import getpass

login = 'nu nu nu'
tokenAddress = "https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=%s&password=%s"
resp = request(tokenAddress % (login, ("nu nu nu"))).json()
mainUserId = 'nu nu nu'
is_start = False

# Авторизация и получение токена "Implicit flow"
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=resp["access_token"])
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def spam_post():
    for i in range(0,3):
        vk.wall.post(owner_id=nu nu nu, message="все получилось")
spam_post()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ограничения на кол-во постов в день. 25 штук, вроде, если от имени сообщества, а если от имени пользователя - неограниченное количество.

Comment: нуууууу, я проверил проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, `owner_id` необходимо брать с поста на стене группы.